# How to realize multiple overwriting of class methods

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In my exampe below, I want to set the alignmet for the first and the second column of the tableview in two different classes. But it does not work as I want.
In my example is only the alignment of the first column set.

The reason why I want to do this is, because I want to make some base settings in a base-widget-class and then, if needed, I want to make addition settings in a subclassed widget.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        model = FirstModel(4, 2)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 0), "a", Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 1), 2, Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(1, 0), "b", Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(1, 1), 4, Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(2, 0), "c", Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(2, 1), 6, Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(3, 0), "d", Qt.EditRole)
        model.setData(model.index(3, 1), 8, Qt.EditRole)

        tableview = QTableView()
        tableview.setModel(model)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class SecondModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        super().data(index, role)

        # set Alignment for column 1
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 1:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        return QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)


class FirstModel(SecondModel):

    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        super().data(index, role)

        # set Alignment for column 0
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter

        return QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    table_view = MyWidget()
    table_view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will start explaining the solution and thereby understand the OP error.

#### Solution:

Before override a method, it must be understood what that method does. The `data()` method aims to return information related to a role and a QModelIndex.

Considering the above in SecondModel, you must return `Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter` when the role is `Qt.TextAlignmentRole` and the column is "1", in the other cases you want to behave like the parent(QStandardItemModel) then you must use `super()`:

```py
class SecondModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 1:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
        return super().data(index, role)
```

The same should be done with FirstModel:

```py
class FirstModel(SecondModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
        return super().data(index, role)
```

---

#### OP error explanation:

```py
class SecondModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        super().data(index, role)
        # set Alignment for column 1
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 1:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
        return QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)
```

In this code it is equivalent to mine in functionality but it has an unnecessary code since `super().data(index, role)` only returns something but the OP does not use the result. Also in this case `super().data(index, role)` is the same as `QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)`.

```py
class FirstModel(SecondModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        super().data(index, role)
        # set Alignment for column 0
        if role == Qt.TextAlignmentRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
        return QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)
```

In this case `super().data(index, role)` does not equal `QStandardItemModel.data(self, index, role)`  because the parent of `FirstModel` is not `QStandardItemModel` but `SecondModel`.  So by not calling the method of `SecondModel` you are deleting the inherited behavior of `SecondModel`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation and solution. Works as requested